# Button is not visible on iPhone 8 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c

Started to test my game on various devices. Every device works well except iPhone 8 Plus. On any other device and the Simulator (even simulated iPhone 8 Plus) the button is visible, but on iPhone 8 Plus it's not. I don't have a clue why this is happening.

1st pic shows Simulator 8 Plus screen, 2nd pic shows device screen.

Here's the code:

```
proceedButton = [[SelectionButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2.0 - 60.00, [[ScreenSize sharedSize] yValue] + 10.0 + [[ScreenSize sharedSize] gameFieldSize], 120.0, [[ScreenSize sharedSize] opButtonSize]) andText:NSLocalizedString(@"DONEKey", @"Done")];
[proceedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createPlayer) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[proceedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changePathColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:proceedButton];
```

[image: On Simulator]

[image: On device]

Comment: Why don't you work with auto layout?

Comment: I started project almost 2 years ago and didn't use it then. Now I have 13K strings of code. I don't think it's a good idea to change that. You think that's the reason? But it works on Simulator.

Comment: did you print the frame values in both simulator and real device ? i think you have to add frame console within your question.

Comment: V12, thanks for your comment. I found out that on device the height of the button ([[ScreenSize sharedSize] opButtonSize]) is equal to 0. That's really weird because it works right on any other Plus devices. The resolution is  1242 x 2208, right? So why this is happening then?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to V12 who pointed me in right direction I found the reason of that matter.

The problem was in that

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

and

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size;
```

are the two different things.

At first I didn't understand why it worked on Simulator and not worked on real device. But when I printed frame values for both device and Simulator, I realised that value for Simulator was equal to values of iPhones 6,7,8 and value for real iPhone 8 Plus was equal to 2201. So I always was getting wrong results.

[This link helped a lot, especially some of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775779/how-to-check-screen-size-of-iphone-4-and-iphone-5-programmatically-in-swift/27776671#27776671)